MAUI iOS crash app within DevExpress package
I get crash app(only iOS) when try use DevExpress controls editor. Support of DevExpress keep quiet, maybe somebody there can help me. I use last version devexpress package, amd use only AutoCompleteEditor. On android all okay, iOS - error.
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
    .UseMauiCompatibility()
    .RegisterServices()
    .UseSkiaSharp()
    .UseMauiMaps()
    .UseBarcodeReader()
    .UseMauiPdfView()
    .UseDevExpress()
    .UseDevExpressEditors()
    .UseDevExpressControls()
    .UseDevExpressCollectionView()
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        fonts.AddFont("SFProText-Regular.ttf", "SFProTextRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("SFProText-Bold.ttf", "SFProTextBold");
    }).UseMauiMaps();


                                     


ObjCRuntime.ObjCException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[DXListView setShowHeader:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x131fd7c00 Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afd79418
55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 37912  1   libobjc.A.dylib
0x00000001a9059c28 objc_exception_throw + 56  2   CoreFoundation
0x00000001afeda400 55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 1483776     3
UIKitCore                           0x00000001b29a4300
27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 13210368   4   CoreFoundation
0x00000001afd8e8b8 55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 125112  5
CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afdf08fc
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92    6   DriverHelper2                       0x000000010504e088 xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path + 8604
7   DriverHelper2                       0x000000010500995c
DriverHelper2 + 825692    8   DriverHelper2
0x0000000105371fcc AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2851792   9
DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105366724
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2804520  10  DriverHelper2
0x0000000105364218 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2795036
11  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105332e9c
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2593440  12  DriverHelper2
0x00000001052da600 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2230788
13  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001052de384
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2246536  14  DriverHelper2
0x00000001053b345c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3119200
15  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001053b9e14
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3146264  16  DXEditors
0x0000000105a87988 -[DXItemsEditBase setDelegate:] + 92   17  DXEditors
0x0000000105a8970c -[DXAutocompleteEdit setDelegate:] + 64    18
DriverHelper2                       0x000000010504e088
xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path + 8604    19  DriverHelper2
0x00000001053732cc AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2856656
20  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105371c40
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2850884  21  DriverHelper2
0x000000010536664c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2804304
22  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105364218
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2795036  23  DriverHelper2
0x0000000105332e9c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2593440
24  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001052da600
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2230788  25  DriverHelper2
0x00000001052de384 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2246536
26  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001053a12e0
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3045092  27  DriverHelper2
0x00000001053e5278 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3323516
28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b205e9c8
27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 3488200    29  UIKitCore
0x00000001b1d241f4 27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 102900  30
UIKitCore                           0x00000001b1fc4cc4
27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 2858180    31  UIKitCore
0x00000001b1e9bf7c 27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 1642364     32
UIKitCore                           0x00000001b1e9b428
27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 1639464    33  UIKitCore
0x00000001b1e9aab4 27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 1637044     34
UIKitCore                           0x00000001b1e9aa1c
27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 1636892    35  UIKitCore
0x00000001b1d0f3e4 27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 17380   36
QuartzCore                          0x00000001b121560c
9E40B2EB-260C-3AF1-AE45-A1A551A8C1B9 + 38412  37  QuartzCore
0x00000001b1227f2c 9E40B2EB-260C-3AF1-AE45-A1A551A8C1B9 + 114476  38
QuartzCore                          0x00000001b12389f0
9E40B2EB-260C-3AF1-AE45-A1A551A8C1B9 + 182768     39  QuartzCore
0x00000001b1265dc0 9E40B2EB-260C-3AF1-AE45-A1A551A8C1B9 + 368064  40
QuartzCore                          0x00000001b1250dbc
9E40B2EB-260C-3AF1-AE45-A1A551A8C1B9 + 282044     41  CoreFoundation
0x00000001afdf98e8 55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 563432  42
CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afd8951c
55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 103708     43  CoreFoundation
0x00000001afde5214 55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 479764  44
CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afde9d20
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584    45  GraphicsServices
0x00000001e7eb5998 GSEventRunModal + 160  46  UIKitCore
0x00000001b207c448 27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 3609672     47
UIKitCore                           0x00000001b207c0c0
UIApplicationMain + 312   48  DriverHelper2
0x00000001050205f4 xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 60     49  DriverHelper2
0x0000000105373340 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2856772
50  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105371c40
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2850884  51  DriverHelper2
0x000000010536664c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2804304
52  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105364218
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2795036  53  DriverHelper2
0x0000000105332e9c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2593440
54  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001052da600
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2230788  55  DriverHelper2
0x00000001052e08fc AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2256128
56  DriverHelper2                       0x000000010533849c
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2615456  57  DriverHelper2
0x000000010504cffc xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path + 4368
58  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001053a0a78
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3042940  59  dyld
0x00000001cd5a4344 8A4B89B7-D348-375B-97B1-FC8A84E3E5CE + 82756
at DevExpress.iOS.ListView.DXListView.set_ShowHeader(Boolean value)
at
DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Internal.DXCollectionViewHandler.ApplyPropertyChange(String
propertyName)    at
DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Internal.DXCollectionViewHandler.AssignProperties()
at
DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Internal.DXCollectionViewHandler.ConnectHandler(DXListView
nativeView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.DXCollectionViewBase, DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.ListView.DXListView, DXCollectionView.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].OnConnectHandler(UIView platformView)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnConnectHandler(Object platformView)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.ConnectHandler(Object platformView)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.DXCollectionViewBase,
DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.ListView.DXListView,
DXCollectionView.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetVirtualView(IView view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.DXCollectionViewBase, DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.ListView.DXListView, DXCollectionView.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)  at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)    at DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.ItemsEditBaseHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit,
DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit,
DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].GetContentView()    at
DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.ItemsEditBaseHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit, DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.IDXItemsEditDelegateImpl.GetContentView() at DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.ItemsEditBaseDelegate1[[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit,
DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].DevExpress.iOS.Editors.IDXItemsEditDelegate.GetContentView()
at DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEditBase.set_WeakDelegate(NSObject
value)    at
DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.EditBaseHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit, DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetupNativeControl()    at DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.ItemsEditBaseHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit,
DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit,
DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetupNativeControl()    at
DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.AutoCompleteEditHandler.SetupNativeControl()
at
DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.EditBaseHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit, DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].ConnectHandler(DXAutocompleteEdit nativeView)    at DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.AutoCompleteEditHandler.ConnectHandler(DXAutocompleteEdit nativeView)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit,
DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit,
DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].OnConnectHandler(UIView
platformView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnConnectHandler(Object
platformView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.ConnectHandler(Object
platformView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit, DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetVirtualView(IView view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.AutoCompleteEdit,
DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXAutocompleteEdit,
DXEditors.i, Version=24.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler
value)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)  at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.BorderHandler.UpdateContent(IBorderHandler handler)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.BorderHandler.MapContent(IBorderHandler handler, IBorderView border)    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IBorderView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IBorderHandler,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)    at
Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key,
IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler
viewHandler, IElement virtualView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.IBorderView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.BorderHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.IBorderView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler
value)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)  at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ScrollViewHandler.UpdateContentView(IScrollView scrollView, IScrollViewHandler handler, ICrossPlatformLayout crossPlatformLayout)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ScrollViewHandler.MapContent(IScrollViewHandler handler, IScrollView scrollView)    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IScrollViewHandler,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)    at
Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key,
IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler
viewHandler, IElement virtualView)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIScrollView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=17.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IView view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIScrollView, Microsoft.iOS,
Version=17.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler
value)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)  at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.set_Handler(IViewHandler value)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded(VisualElement view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load() at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement,
Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].SetElement(VisualElement element)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement(VisualElement element)    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.RendererToHandlerShim.SetVirtualView(IView view)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.IView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=17.2.0.0,
Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler
value)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler
handler)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler
handler, IContentView page)    at
Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView,
Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler
value)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ViewExtensions.ToHandler(IView view,
IMauiContext context)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRootRenderer.SetPageRenderer(Page
page, ShellContent shellContent)    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRootRenderer.LoadRenderers()
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRootRenderer.ViewDidLoad()
at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv,
IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName) in
/Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line
58    at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass,
Type delegateClass) in
/Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line
94    at DriverHelper2.Program.Main(String[] args) in
/Users/mac/RiderProjects/MAUI/DriverHelper v 2.0/DriverHelper v
2.0/Platforms/iOS/Program.cs:line 13 Native stack trace:  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afd79418
55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 37912  1   libobjc.A.dylib
0x00000001a9059c28 objc_exception_throw + 56  2   CoreFoundation
0x00000001afeda400 55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 1483776     3
UIKitCore                           0x00000001b29a4300
27A9C298-B702-3C39-8C06-07196E4CD16B + 13210368   4   CoreFoundation
0x00000001afd8e8b8 55B9BA28-4C5C-3FE7-9C47-4983337D6E83 + 125112  5
CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afdf08fc
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92    6   DriverHelper2                       0x000000010504e088 xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path + 8604
7   DriverHelper2                       0x000000010500995c
DriverHelper2 + 825692    8   DriverHelper2
0x0000000105371fcc AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2851792   9
DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105366724
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2804520  10  DriverHelper2
0x0000000105364218 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2795036
11  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105332e9c
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2593440  12  DriverHelper2
0x00000001052da600 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2230788
13  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001052de384
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2246536  14  DriverHelper2
0x00000001053b345c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3119200
15  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001053b9e14
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 3146264  16  DXEditors
0x0000000105a87988 -[DXItemsEditBase setDelegate:] + 92   17  DXEditors
0x0000000105a8970c -[DXAutocompleteEdit setDelegate:] + 64    18
DriverHelper2                       0x000000010504e088
xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path + 8604    19  DriverHelper2
0x00000001053732cc AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2856656
20  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105371c40
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2850884  21  DriverHelper2
0x000000010536664c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2804304
22  DriverHelper2                       0x0000000105364218
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2795036  23  DriverHelper2
0x0000000105332e9c AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2593440
24  DriverHelper2                       0x00000001052da600
AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2230788  25  DriverHelper2
0x00000001052de384 AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection + 2246536


With the 24.1.3 version, you need to set the localization it seems "useLocalization: false". Make sure you have that included in MauiProgram.cs
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseDevExpress(useLocalization: false)
        .UseDevExpressCollectionView()
        .UseDevExpressControls()
        .UseDevExpressEditors()


deleting folders obj and bin and clear cache nuget helped me. Thanks for answer.
